# tlcockpit and tlmgr

Tags: tlmgr, update

I hope that this question is suitable for this forum:
I have been experiencing difficulty with tlmgr generally. I found that there is a highly recommended GUI for tlmgr, tlcockpit. This was supposed to be part of the texlive distribution that I initially installed mid-December 2022, but it is not there. I then managed to use chown to gain access to the folder
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts
where I created the folder 'tlcockpit', and put the file 'tlcockpit.jar (all according to instructions at [GIT website for tlcockpit](https://github.com/TeX-Live/tlcockpit). So far, so good. Or so it seemed.
When I launch the tlcockpit GUI, it tries its best to show the packages (installed ones) and the (possible) updates that are available. But the hamster wheel keeps spinning, and nothing is loaded.
It seems to me that there may be problems with the PATH or other environment variables. Maybe it cannot find its way...

Comment: My guess is that tlcockpit merely provides a GUI to tlmgr, so if tlmgr is not working for you, no help.

Comment: The `tlmgr` command  has its own simple GUI, try `tlmgr --gui`.